# What refactoring would make this method testable

Tags: c#-4.0

so I have

```
 /// <summary>
        ///We cannot sell to someone who's address postcode is Channel Islands = GY 
        /// or Isle of Man = IM.
        /// So there are three possibilities... an unclear channel islands I.D. needs a pop up, an error or invalid country needs a pop up and a good match can display policyholder
        ///
        /// </summary>
        public void ValidateAddressCanPurchaseInsurance(PolicyHolder p)
        {
            if (p == null) {DisplayErrorPopup(@"Could not check address for this person - Dang!"); return;}

            var countryResult = IdentifyUnavailableAddresses(p);

            if (countryResult == UnavailableAddressMatch.UnmatchedChannelIslands) {DisplayErrorPopup("Couldn't determine whether this Channel Islands resident is Jersey or Guernsey based... fix postcode and retry application"); return;}
            if (countryResult == UnavailableAddressMatch.Guernsey || countryResult == UnavailableAddressMatch.IsleOfMan) { DisplayErrorPopup(countryResult); return;}
            if (countryResult == UnavailableAddressMatch.None) { DisplayPolicyHolder(p); return; }
            DisplayErrorPopup(String.Format("Something very odd has gone on while trying to validate the address of this person! {0}",p.MembershipNumber));
        }
```

Which I can't really test... I can obviously test IdentifyUnavailableAddresses() and do but I'd like to pass a set of policyHolders to this method and see that it behaves as I expect.

Display Error Popup will take an UnavailableAddressMatch enum and format a pop-up message appropriately or take a string and put it in a pop-up

This method lives in a class that determines the behaviour of a Windows Form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValidateAddressCanPurchaseInsurance` is a business layer method. `DisplayErrorPopup` is a UI thing. They do not belong in the same class.

Putting `DisplayErrorPopup` in another class makes it possible to put a mock object in your unit test and check whether `DisplayErrorPopup` is called.

Comment: Hmmm, DisplayErrorPopup only calls a method on the parent UI so I could instead have a method that makes the error message string and then just call the Parent popup. Then I can mock the parent...

Comment: Incidentally, I agree that the ValidateAddressCanPurchaseInsurance and DisplayErrorPopup shouldn't live side by side but that's a job for tomorrow and tomorrow and tomorrow...

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sjoerd that the `DisplayErrorPopUp` doesn't belong in this class. But I'd go even further and say that the call to `DisplayErrorPopUp` doesn't belong here either. I'd say this method should throw an Exception and the caller should catch and display an error message depending on exception. You might want to handle the exception different in different views.

Edit: Oh and what you test is that the method is throwing the correct exceptions. You don't have to care about the `DisplayErrorPopup` since that is tested in the views tests for how to handle different exceptions.